# processing sound, library not installed properly

Tags: java, audio, this, processing

So im trying to play this sound but it is not working. i get this message

```
Error: Soundfile doesn't exist. Pleae check path
A library relies on native code that's not available.
Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit application.
and A library used by this sketch is not installed properly
```

I don't know where im going wrong here

here's the code

```
SoundFile file;
void setup(){
   size (300,300);
   background(100,150,0);
   file= new SoundFile(this,"Deadmau5.mp3"); 
   file.play();
}

void draw(){

}
```

is it that it is not looking in the right directory for the file?
can anyone break this down for me please?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot going on there. You might want to copy the full text of the error instead of paraphrasing. But here are a few things I might check if I were you:

Is the library installed correctly? Are you installing it from the Processing editor, or are you trying to do it manually? Have you included all of the native libraries required?

Does the library require you to run it as a 32-bit application? If so, are you doing that?

Have you added the file to your sketch by going to the Sketch menu, then clicking the "add file" option? Take a look in your sketch directory- is the file where you think it should be?

Comment: ive added the file to processing but still same error, and i dont think i am running it as a 32 bit application how do i do so

Comment: sorry im such a noob lol.
i get no errors with the line of code that ive written though

Comment: ive installed it through the import library

Comment: @user3318928 Well, there are two kinds of errors: compilation errors and runtime errors. Compilation errors just tell you when your syntax is wrong. But runtime errors can still happen if your logic or setup are wrong.

Comment: shall i use minim instead?

Comment: @user3318928 It's entirely up to you. That's certainly an option.

Comment: would that be better?

Comment: @user3318928 That's going to depend entirely on what you're trying to do, what your personal preferences are, etc. If you're having trouble getting this library working, then trying out minim is a reasonable thing to try.

Comment: ==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TDEN

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TSSE
this deadfull message came up

Comment: import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
void setup()
{
  size (300, 300);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player=minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3");
  
}

void mousePressed()
{
    // play the file
    player.play();
}

Comment: import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
void setup()
{
  size (300, 300);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player=minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3");
  
}

void mousePressed()
{
    // play the file
    player.play();
}

Comment: This really isn't how Stack Overflow works. Comments aren't really meant for this kind of discussion. What error message are you getting now that you're using minim?

Comment: true, sorry to do that

Comment: ==== JavaSound Minim Error ==== ==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX ==== JavaSound Minim Error ==== ==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX ==== JavaSound Minim Error ==== ==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX ==== JavaSound Minim Error ==== ==== Don't know the ID3 code TDEN ==== JavaSound Minim Error ==== ==== Don't know the ID3 code TSSE. I am looking at other alternatives to find the reason fo rthis error

Comment: @user3318928 Since you're now using a different library and getting a different error, you might consider asking a new question with your updated code as a [mcve].